# Django write from template to context

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates

I have javascript which gets scrollHeight from page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

       var body = document.body,
       html = document.documentElement;

       var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                                   html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
       document.write(height);
</script>
```

In my case, i need to get this height in template tags. Is it possible to write this scrollHeight number from template to context?

Comment: You mean during the same page request?

Comment: Yes. So that in my template tag i can calculate page number by scrollHeight.

Answer (score 1):

There is an important distinction between Django templates and in-browser JavaScript that you seem to be missing:

*Django is executed on the server side, while JavaScript is executed on the client side.*

That means that (within a single request) Django templates are always executed *before* JavaScript (as it is executed by the server, before the page is sent to the client). As a consequence it is absolutely impossible to mix JavaScript and Django code the way you want to.

JavaScript running in the browser means that templates had been already evaluated on the server and sent to the browser. It is simply to late to set template context at this point. The train has already left the station.

You need to accept that this method is impossible and find another way to achieve your goal. I won't advise you on this, because I don't have any specific information about the feature you are working on. At this point I can just speculate. Most likely you should sent a generic hight-independent version of your site from the server, and then use JavaScript to apply the changes resulting from the specific `height` value. Or maybe just rewrite your (CSS?) code so the value is no longer needed - if this is even possible in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Because - during the same request - first django template code is run on the server and *after that* the js code is run in the browser you can easily use django template context values in your js code but not the reverse. You can though send js values to the server through AJAX. But this in a second - although asynchronous - request.

Comment: But in my case, i need reverse. Then maybe i can write from javascript to request or context? Is it possible?